# jQuery $(window).resize(function() {

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make this code applies only at a resolution greater than 643px. If we use " $ (window) .resize (function () {" not working. I'm not good at JQuery syntax, please help.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() >= 643) {        

    function mainmenu(){
        $("#nav ul").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix

        $("#nav li").hover(function() {
            $(this).find('ul:first')
                .css({visibility: "visible", display:"none"})
                .show(500);
        }, function() {
            $(this).find('ul:first')
                .css({visibility: "hidden"});
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        mainmenu();
    });

    $(" #nav a").removeAttr("title");
});
```

Comment: Resolution? I assume that you are referring to the body width when you say 643px.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle.net with what you've tried and a simple example of your current problem?

Comment: where is problem in my code?

Comment: I dont' think you need a resize function. You just need to add the `if($(window).width() >= 643)` code inside your mainmenu function

Comment: ok, it is function. thank

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 643) {
        // do something
        console.log("width is now larger than 643px");
    } else {
        console.log("width is now smaller or equal to 643px");
    }
});
```

You can run this code in the console of any page (such as this one), resize it, and watch the output.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to deduce your problem from the information you've provided, but here's an attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var initFn = function(){
        if($(window).width() >= 643){
           mainmenu();
           $(" #nav a").removeAttr("title");
        }
    } 

    $(window).resize(initFn);

    initFn();

});

function mainmenu(){
    $("#nav ul").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix

    $("#nav li").hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul:first')
            .css({visibility: "visible", display:"none"})
            .show(500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('ul:first')
            .css({visibility: "hidden"});
    });
}
```